# Trying to run or include javascript in the head of page using Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

So, this it my code:

```
extends layout
doctype html
html(lang="en")
head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    title = My Page Title
    script(type="text/javascript",src="../javascripts/jquery-git2.js")
    script(type="text/javascript").
        console.log("this should work, right?")
    body
        block content
            h1= title
            div !{article}
```

Strangely enough, the scripts run and include just fine when I put them in the body, but I want them in the header. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance! I'm totally stuck on this one.

Comment: Can you try adding a title to be more compliant to the specs? below meta utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out! I'm new to Jade and didn't know that the head was taken care of by the layout.jade file. Once I placed the script references in the layout.jade file under the head where they belong, everything worked fine. Thanks for your help and suggestions everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Your template generates nested `<script>` tags.

Try unindenting the second `script`:

```
script(type="text/javascript",src="../javascripts/jquery-git2.js")
script(type="text/javascript").
    console.log("this should work, right?")
```

Comment: please post the layout too. Skipping the layout it works for me.

Comment: also it should be `title= "My Page Title"`